# PostgreSQL: Top 10 games by total number of daily sessions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working on a problem where I have to find the top 10 games by total number of daily sessions on Jan 7th 2019.

column: user_id, date, game_name, session_count

Here is what I have but I'm not sure if it's correct?

```
with t1 as 
(select game_name, session_count,
dense_rank() over(order by session_count desc) as dr
from instant_game_sessions
where game_date = '2019-01-07')

select * from t1 
where dr <=10
```

SQL Fiddle link provided [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5982b/2).

Comment: This looks correct.  Note that if you just wanted the top 10 while ignoring ties, then use `ROW_NUMBER` instead of `DENSE_RANK`.

Comment: Your query looks just fine. @TimBiegeleisen made a good point, keep in mind that your rank might have ties and you should decide how to deal with them ;) cheers

Comment: @JimJones Thanks, the reason why I ask my question is because my alternative answer was this (pastebin.com/NV90tNM1), but I wasn't sure if it was correct. Would you happen to know? Thanks in advance.